# Get past 20 rows in a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to calculate the 20 day simple moving average of stock data from a data frame called `data`
These are the column names of the data frame:
`1. open   2. high  3. low  4. close 5. SMA`

I want each value in the SMA to be the average of the past 20 values in  `4. close`
I tried using
`data['5. SMA'] = np.average(data['4. close'][:21])`
 but it only returns a single value throughout the data column (which is understandable because the code works on the first 20 values only). However, I for each row in `5. SMA`, I want to work with the past 20 values in `4. close`.
How can I implement this using numpy or pandas?

Comment: Try `df.rolling` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually googling pandas documentation gives a great outcome. Try [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.mean.html) perhaps:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])
s.rolling(2).mean()
0    NaN
1    1.5
2    2.5
3    3.5
dtype: float64
```